# Extracting data from XSD in XSL

Tags: xslt, xsd

I am transforming an XML file that needs to generate some elements based on the valid enumeration options defined in the XSD.

Suppose I have an XSD that declares a type and an element something like this:

```
<xs:simpleType name="optionType" nillable="true">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:maxLength value="50"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="USERCHOICE">
        </xs:enumeration>
        <xs:enumeration value="DEFAULT">
        </xs:enumeration>
        </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
...
<xs:element name="chosenOption" type='optionType'/>
...
<xs:element name="availableOption" type='optionType'/>
```

The input will only contain the chosen option, so you can imagine it looks like this:

```
<options>
     <chosenOption>USERCHOICE</chosenOption>
</options>
```

I need to have an output that looks like this:

```
<options>
    <chosenOption>USERCHOICE</chosenOption> <!-- This comes from incoming XML -->

    <!-- This must be a list of ALL possible values for this element, as defined in XSD -->
    <availableOptions>
        <availableOption>USERCHOICE</availableOption>
        <availableOption>DEFAULT</availableOption>
    </availableOptions>
</options>
```

Is there a way to have the XSL extract the enumeration values `USERCHOICE` and `DEFAULT` from the XSD and produce them in the output?

This will run on WebSphere 6 and will be used by an XSLT 1.0 engine. :(

(The schema file does not change often but it *will* change now and then and I'd rather only have to update the schema file instead of update the schema file and XSLT)

Comment: I would fix the post to make it consistent; right now, your XSD shows `optionType` and your XMLs show `chosenOption`. What is the link between the two? A human can do some inference based on your question; you'll have to make it clear to your transformation through explicit metadata or conventions. You need to tie the location of the XSD, the XML tag name (or XPath) and the appropriate XML Schema type.

Comment: @PetruGardea: Good point. The actual example is quite a bit more complex, I think I mangled something in my attempt to clean it up. The basic point is that an incoming element is restricted to values in an enumeration. The consumer of the transformed XML needs a list of all available options that the element *could* be restricted to.

Comment: For a pure XSLT solution, you would need to have access to an XSLT 2.0 engine that is XSD aware - [Saxon-EE](http://www.saxonica.com/feature-matrix.html) is the one that springs to my mind here - that is for sure. And even then I doubt it is possible to have it interoperable and achieve your goal to modify only the XSD, in any arbitrary way you may think of. On the other hand, as an e.g., on .NET you can easily build such a solution, without XSLT, absolutely to your requirement of having XSD as the only artifact that needs to be maintained.

Comment: @PetruGardea: Thanks. I wasn't sure it was possible (it sounds like it isn't, for me). This will run on WebSphere 6 and it is not capable of processing XSLT 2.0.

Comment: I would disagree with @PetruGardea. Even though XSLT 1.0 doesn't have all the schema-awareness features, it can just treat the XSD like any other XML document, and look up the data it needs using XPath. Why not?

Comment: Ooooo.... WAS 6; if you're in a locked down environment, then for sure you're out of luck! There is not way to do it correctly without PSVI. I hope someone like @Michael Kay chimes in regardless... If it turns out you need to go down the Java path, start with this [stub](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/faq-xs.html) - if supported by your WAS configuration.

Comment: @LarsH, this would be working for very simple scenarios. While XSD is just XML, what is really needed here - given the requirements - is access to PSVI. And that is only what an XSD aware processor can give... I can easily show you an XSD and XML that would make the XSLT programmer behind it quickly give up.

Comment: @PetruGardea: If I know the exact XPATH to the values in the XSD, would it be possible to do what I want without having a schema-aware XSLT engine?

Comment: Yes. But you will not be able  to `I'd rather only have to update the schema file instead of update the schema file and XSLT`. You go back to my initial comment that you need a way to maintain the link between a tag and its type definition to an XSD file. It should be simple if all is in one XSD, also.

Comment: @PetruGardea: Well, I'd try to design the XSLT so that it gets all of the enumeration values as a node-set and then iterate through them. The *path* to the enumeration shouldn't change, just adding/removing specific items.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a prototype that assumes that your input XML and XSD are as simple as the samples above. To be tweaked according to ways in which they may vary. If you need help with that tweaking, let me know.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
   version="1.0">

   <xsl:variable name="xsd" select="document('mySchema.xsd')"/>

   <xsl:template match="/options">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:variable name="eltName" select="local-name()"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="." />
            <availableOptions>
               <xsl:variable name="optionType"
                  select="$xsd//xs:element[@name = $eltName]/@type"/>
               <xsl:apply-templates
                  select="$xsd//xs:simpleType[@name = $optionType]/
                       xs:restriction/xs:enumeration"/>
            </availableOptions>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="xs:enumeration">
      <availableOption><xsl:value-of select="@value" /></availableOption>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I share @Petru's concern for sufficient generality. I offer the above in case full generality (e.g. for complex Schema changes) is not needed. My impression from the question description is that the Schema will only vary in simple, predictable ways, but I may be wrong.

Comment: To further illustrate my comment to you, using your code. Ideally, one would want to decouple the XSLT from the authoring style. An XSD may change, with no net effect to the PSVI (different XSDs may validate same XML). Your code relies a lot on knowing exactly how the XSD was written; which then bears the question why not simply hardcode the values? The reason I am saying this, is to account for real life implementations; it just gives a false sense of security that artifacts are decoupled (XSD from XSLT) when in fact, they're not.

Comment: @LarsH: That's a fair point. I've been asked to do this on the assumption that the *only* schema changes are the addition/removal of enumeration values. If they start making significant changes outside of what they promised, then all bets are off.

Comment: @PetruGardea: Agreed, on the danger of the XSD changing in arbitrary ways; especially since, if that happens, no error message will be given. (If desired, one could add an `<xsl:message terminate='yes'>` to trigger, or else omit all output of the stylesheet, when no enumeration of the expected structure is found, thus causing a possible serialization or parsing error downstream. But I don't how effective that would be in WebSphere.) It would be up to the OP to evaluate those risks w.r.t. the benefits.